# SSH known_hosts ignored on one machine

Tags: ssh, rsync, ansible

I am experience strange behavior using ssh with a jump host. While the setup works on machine A (*cygwin, OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015*) it does not work on machine B (*OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014*). This setup is supposed to be used by Ansible to connect to remote machines via the bastion host.

I have the following `ssh.config`

```
Host bastion
    HostName               a.a.a.a
    ProxyCommand           none
    UserKnownHostsFile     known_hosts

Host *
    User                   user
    Port                   22
    ForwardAgent           yes
    ProxyCommand           ssh forward@a.a.a.a nc %h %p
    PasswordAuthentication no
    UserKnownHostsFile     known_hosts
```

The `known_hosts` files resides in the same folder.

Calling

```
ssh bastion -F ssh.config
```

works on both machines. While

```
ssh user@b.b.b.b -F ssh.config
```

does work only on machine A and not on B resulting in

```
The authenticity of host 'a.a.a.a (a.a.a.a)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is ###.
```

I tried changing the proxy command to

```
ProxyCommand ssh forward@a.a.a.a -F ssh.config nc %h %p
```

This solved the issue with

```
ssh user@b.b.b.b -F ssh.config
```

as it now worked on both machines. The config however is used also by `rsync` which is run by Ansible and as this is run from another base directory the `ssh.config` file cannot be found. I do not want to use absolute paths to allow for portability. The scripts are supposed to be run on local machines (some Windows with `cygwin`) as well as by a dedicated build server using remote agents.

I have now set `ProxyCommand` to

```
ProxyCommand ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no forward@a.a.a.a nc %h %p
```

This works on A+B but has also issues with `rsync`/`ansible`. The log gives me:

```
msg: Warning: Permanently added 'a.a.a.a' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Host key verification failed.

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

TL;DR The initial configuration would not work headless as it required a manual step to set the host keys. The alternatives did break the following workflow (`rsync`). Any other options?

Answer (score 2):

Possibility to "workaround" the security of host-keys is to use `ssh-keyscan` which will create you the `known_hosts` file and then you can connect without checking authenticity of the host manually.

It can be used like this:

```
ssh-keyscan hostname > known_hosts
```

You will loose the "one point" of security, but if this runs in trusted environment, it is acceptable.

Comment: Could point. I will give it a try. Meanwhile I have resorted to not checking keys at all. Using ssh-keyscan would actually improve this.